# Exit kiosk mode with local account in windows 10

Tags: wpf, powershell, windows-10, kiosk-mode

I tried to set up kiosk mode for my laptop to run WPF single app. Firstly, I turn on Shell Launcher in **Turn Windows features on or off** and run script in powershell with admin right to open my WPF app then restart device.

After restart and login local account (only this account in my laptop), my laptop always displayed a black screen and I can't do anything. What is the problem and how to exit kiosk mode. Now, only pressing Ctrl + Alt + DEl key is working but still can not exist kiosk mode.
Please help me!

Comment: "run script in powershell with admin right to open my WPF app then restart device." - why are you using admin-level permissions here?

Comment: _"only this account in my laptop"_ - Kiosk mode **requires** another user-account with which it can override the locked-down Kiosk-mode account - so you should fix that, no?

Comment: "why are you using admin-level permissions here?" --because the script makes error if not run with admin right

Comment: "Kiosk mode requires another user-account with which it can override the locked-down Kiosk-mode account - so you should fix that, no?" -- sorry, I don't know need another account for kiosk mode so I dont' create it and now I can not exist kiosk mode in my local account and my screen is always black

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit Kiosk mode in your case by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd>;then, select "Task Manager" → "File" → "Run" and enter "explorer.exe".

This will run the normal Windows Explorer shell.

Comment: so great. It's working! Tks you so much